# Sort results without WP_QUERY?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, taxonomy, sort

I am new to coding a WP_QUERY and I tried a few things with it but it doesn't seem to work. Right now (you can see the page here: http://boomerang.mannydesigns.co/artistes/parcourir/musique/ )

I need to reorganize the ordering of these artists by a custom field I added (with ACF) name exclusif which is a selection field with 3 choices.

Is it possible to do so without doing a WP_QUERY & simply adding to the current code (which is the usual post loop)?

```
    /**
 * Alters queries
 */
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wp_order_artists' );
function wp_order_artists( $query ) {

    // don't run on the backend
    if ( is_admin() )
      return;

    // Only run on post types artists
    if ( is_post_type_archive('artists') && $query->is_main_query() || $post_type == 'artists' ) {

        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'exclusif' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
    }

    return;
}
if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <div class="remix_items grid clearfix <?php echo $artists_col; ?>">
        <?php while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
            <a class="item<?php $i++; echo ($i % $artists_col_num === 0) ? ' last_item' : ''; ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark">
                <figure class="effect-bubba">
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                         the_post_thumbnail('type_cover');
                        } else {
                            echo '<img src="" alt="'.the_title().'">';
                        } ?>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                        </figcaption>
                </figure>
            </a>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
   </div>
```

Comment: WHY WHY WHY in this world have you switched from `pre_get_posts` to `query_posts` `query_posts` is the **WRONG WAY** to run a query. Please search this site, I really do think we have said enough about `query_posts`

Comment: There is just no use is using `$wp_query` if you are breaking it with `query_posts`. It is like buying a new car for work, then driving it into a wall , scrapping it, for no apparent reason at all

Comment: @PieterGoosen I really wish I could upvote that more than once!

Comment: You should roll back the edit to your question and ask a new question. Your edit is a different problem and my current answer doesn't make sense in relation to the edit. If you ask a new question I'll happily take a look at it.

Comment: @PieterGoosen whether I use query_posts or pre_get_posts the terms I use inside to order will be very similar and the purpose of my question is the boolean I'm trying to order it by prior my other terms. I actually have CAI's code as well as this one for testing purposes - just need some help with the boolean I'm trying to order it by...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the order of an already existing query, you shouldn't create a new `WP_Query` object but instead use `pre_get_posts` to alter the existing query, which prevents multiple queries running unnecessarily.

From the `pre_get_posts` [docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts):

> This hook is called after the query variable object is created, but before the actual query is run.

---

This is an example of how to change all queries of a custom post type to order by a custom field. Obviously it will need to be changed to fit your situation but should give you an idea of what to do:

```
/**
 * Alters queries
 */
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_217090_pre_get_posts' );
function wpse_217090_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

    // don't run on the backend
    if ( is_admin() )
      return;

    // Only run on post types 'your_custom_post_type'
    if ( is_post_type_archive('your_custom_post_type') && $query->is_main_query() || $post_type == 'your_custom_post_type' ) {

        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
        $query->set( 'meta_key', '_your_custom_field' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }

    return;
}
```

For reference you should read up on;

- [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)
- [pre_get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)

Comment: Thank you thank you!!!! That's exactly what I've been looking for.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help :)

Comment: Check my answer above to confirm I'm on the right track. I added the code just above my if statement on the taxonomy-artist.php template. Exclusif is the ACF field I want to order the items by.

Comment: The function itself looks fine but it should go in functions.php not the template file

Comment: Is 'artists' a custom post type or custom taxonomy? You need to edit the line if ( is_post_type_archive... to target the correct queries, so if you want it to affect a taxonomy page you will change it to something like if ( is_tax('artist') )

Comment: Artists is a custom post type and exclusif is a choice selection field added to it with ACF. What I was thinking is to have conditional statements with the field (ex.: any artists with 'yes' selected in the exclusif field is on top of the list).  After adding the code to the functions page it doesn't seem to have any impact on it so something seems off. You can see the current temp site if you are curious. boomerang.mannydesigns.co

Comment: you said that you were using the taxonomy-artist.php template? Do you have a custom post type 'Artists' and a custom taxonomy 'Artist'?

Comment: Can you look into my updated code above I figured 80% of the solution based on my issue but need just a little push with the remaining 20%...already tried several ways without success.

Comment: I'll have to have a look at your code when I've got time later but you really really do not want to be using query_posts. As I said in my answer you should be using pre_get_posts to modify the original query, not making a new query. And query_posts is the wrong way of making a new query even if you were going to do that!

Comment: Yes I use both while I'm testing my solutions so no issues here. My issue, and what I've researched and couldn't find an answer (I tried several items) is how to also order it by a meta key that is a boolean first, then by the exclusif meta key, finally by name alphabetically. I got everything except the boolean part.